# Importing csv file into pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

When, I'm importing .csv file into pgAdmin, says error "Missing data for column address".

But there is 3 row in csv file for address column. I don't understand what to do.

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwm6J.png)

Comment: I think this error is associated with the delimiter ';' in your  CSV  file. notice that the command assumes the delimiter is ','  this is likely the cause of your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when trying to import CSV specify a ';' delimiter as in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks